# Task scheduling php file folder issue

Tags: php, xampp

I'm starting a php file with php.exe via console but that php page include same other pages (in /htdocs/*) and a get error because active directory is /php/php.exe. how can i solve the proplem ?

I'm using xampp on Windows 8

```
Command: C:\xampp>php\php.exe -f htdocs\mail_send.php
```

Comment: How are the other files being included? If you post a few lines showing the includes it might give a better indication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
include 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
mkdir("Raporlar/".$Kyıl,"0777");
```

in /xampp/htdocs/mail_send.php

Get error from these lines
Rest of the files inside the same folder to(/htdocs/)